# Android - TableLayout to ExpandableListView

Tags: android, view, tablelayout, expandablelistview

Is it possible to switch from a TableLayout to an ExpandableListView?  How?  I tried using ViewFlipper but the fact that ExpandableListView doesn't use XML threw a wrench in it.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really understand the question in a sense of what do you mean by

> switch from a TableLayout to an
>   ExpandableListView

But ExpandableListView can be defined in xml just fine

```
   <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/myList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I overlooked that.

For a complete implementation check out:

http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.html

It had a few tips in there I used.  Thanks Alex!